# Display ImageBuffer on application window with Rust

Tags: rust, fltk

what is Rust's best way to display and dynamically generated image?

I have

```
let image : ImageBuffer<Rgb<u8>, Vec<u8>> = ...
```

How do I show it in a GUI?

I tried with fltk, but didn't find anything usable for ImageBuffer.

```
use fltk::...

let app = App::default().with_scheme(AppScheme::Gleam);
let mut wind = Window::new(100, 100, 400, 300, "Hello from rust");
wind.set_image(Some(image));
```

won't work because:

```
the trait `ImageExt` is not implemented for image::buffer_::ImageBuffer<image::color::Rgb<u8>, Vec<u8>>`
```

Do I have to encode my ImageBuffer image to some specific format, so that the GUI library can decode it back and display it afterward?

Or maybe I should use some other UI library then fltk?

Comment: I don't know `fltk` but I'd guess that you need to build an [`RgbImage`](https://docs.rs/fltk/latest/fltk/image/struct.RgbImage.html) that does implement `ImageExt`.

Comment: I don't know rust but I know FLTK. In FLTK you would create an Fl_RGB_Image from an image buffer in (R, G, B) or (R, G, B, A) format and assign it to an Fl_Box widget as its label (image).
Someting like:
```
Fl_RGB_Image *img = new Fl_RGB_Image(buffer, ...);
Fl_Box *b = new Fl_Box(x, y, w, h);
b->image(img);
```
I hope you can translate this to rust (fltk-rs). Note that Fl_Box is called "frame" in fltk-rs IIRC, or something like that.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find a way to format the code properly in the comment. Maybe I should have edited an answer but I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: @AlbrechtSchlosser: Take a look at the [SO formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). At the end there is a section about comments.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks for the hint. I read the article but I'm still puzzled. I used three backticks (w/o a language tag). You can still see the backticks in my comment, but it's not formatted as intended. Ah, okay, found one more hint: indenting by 4 spaces should format as code?

Comment: @AlbrechtSchlosser Three ticks in answers for a block of code; one tick for inline code in answers and comments. You can test that in the [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with the help from mo_al_'s answear. I just had to use into_raw(), because to_rgb8() or into_rgb8() were not implemented for type.

```
let w = image.width() as i32;
let h = image.height() as i32;
let image_rgb = RgbImage::new(&domain_image.into_raw(), w, h, ColorDepth::Rgb8).unwrap();
...
let mut frame = Frame::new(0, 0, w, h, "");
frame.set_image(Some(image_rgb));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an fltk RgbImage from an ImageBuffer (from the image crate) using:

```rust
let rgbimage = RgbImage::new(&image.to_rgb8(), image.width() as i32, image.height() as i32, ColorDepth::Rgb8).unwrap();
```